# php exec passthru and tty prompts

Tags: php

I often use PHP to script more complex maintenance tasks. Usually run in CLI, or as cron tasks. I've had decent success with having prompts passed through, and functional with exec and pass-thru.

I never really thought about having web access to these scripts, until something in the documentation made me think it may be possible/useful.

However, almost all of the documentation mentions the output of commands, slim to none information about [CLI] prompts.

It's probably a bad idea in the first place because it would probably inadvertently boost privileges of web server user (www-data), right?

Comment: How would www-data boost it's privileges?

Comment: I think OP is asking to be able to call stuff like `passwd`, `sudo` etc. from a webinterface. In that case `www-data` (or whichever user the site uses) will have to have sudo (or at least extended) privileges. It'd be VERY unsafe unless you're absolutely sure that everything is done perfectly right. What might be easier would be to save a file locally with PHP and have a deamon checking if the file exists and if it does, it'll run your script and save the log to another file. The PHP will then read this file. That doesn't give PHP direct access to commands.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think "run" in the first sentence was supposed as a past participle: "to script tasks (which ones?) usually run in CLI"

Comment: @ob-ivan "ran" is a nonstandard past participle of "run". While technically correct, "run" is the standard past participle. See [this English Language post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390341/168711). Also, it was Grammarly that made the suggestion for me to change it to this version of the word. By all means, if you believe this is incorrect, feel free to change it :)